# Have php switch column value to either 1 or 0

Tags: php, mysql

I'm learning PHP and getting a little frustrated. I have an html form that is sending data to another php page `$_POST["id"];`.

On a 2nd php page I'm trying have the "available" column in the table either switch to 1 or 0. If it's already 1 go to 0, and if it's 0 go to 1.

I know my code is probably completely wrong and messy but please excuse me as I'm still learning.

```
if ($row["available"] == 1) {
    //$row["available"] = 0;
    $sql = "UPDATE check_in_out SET available=0 WHERE id='".$_POST["id"]."'";
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "Record updated successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
    }
} else {
    //$row["available"] = 1;
    $sql = "UPDATE check_in_out SET available=1 WHERE id='".$_POST["id"]."'";
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "Record updated successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
    }
}
```

Comment: what problem you are facing in this..

Comment: Your code is quite (despite the performance issues) ok.. whats your question?

Comment: @mapek answered it! Thanks guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to toggle the value you can use this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE check_in_out SET available = (1-available) WHERE id='".$_POST["id"]."'";
```

or

```
$sql = "UPDATE check_in_out SET available = IF(available = 0, 1, 0) WHERE id='".$_POST["id"]."'";
```

Comment: OMG! haha. You rock! Thank you so so much!